# Entity Framework PK Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ms-access-2010

I work with entity framework 6.0 with code first.

I need to connect to database table created by Microsoft Access ODBC.

When I try to connect to a table, a receive an error about the PK name.

Entity Framework create a PK with name PK_dbo_TABLENAME that create problem with Microsoft Access. If I rename it, there are no problem.

How I can force different name to entity framework key?

I search in data-annotation syntax but with no result.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the [KeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx#Key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I manual rename PK from Sql Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that your column name is not the same name as the property you're using (i.e `TableID` vs `Id`) you can use the `[Column()]` attribute to override the name:

```
[Column("GeoLocationDetailId")]
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

If you're referring to the schema not recognize your Primary Key, you can add the `[Key]` attribute on that property and it will pick it up :

```
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

If you're using Model configuration, you can use the `HasKey` method in the same manner you would with the `[Key]` attribute:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<GeoLocationEntity>()
            .HasKey(e => e.Id)
```

Comment: The problems is the key name under Sql Server. If I open a table, key columns is correct, but if I open Keys folder the costraints name is PK_dbo_tableName.

Comment: You said MS Access - what do you mean Sql Server?

Comment: Entity framework code first create table in SQL Server. I try to connect with Microsoft Access ODBC

Comment: That's the name of the constraint, not the name of the PK

Comment: Sorry, but I'm newbie. Is possibile customize this name? Thanks

Comment: Customize which name?

Comment: Current costraint (pk name) is PK_dbo_tableName. When I create attach table with access, the name is not compatible. I need override default name created by EF and create name as PKTableName.